# Does it always cost an action to spend a healing surge?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing, warlord

The Warlord ability Inspiring Word states that it allows a target to use a healing surge - does it require the target to use a minor action to use such healing surge?  Or is it basically the equivalent to a healing spell assuming that target has a healing surge to spend?

In other words, to use Second Wind (the only time I can use a healing surge in combat) I have to spend a standard action to do so...if my Warlord uses Inspiring Word on me do I need to spend an action to use a healing surge and if so, what type of action?

Answer (score 18):

### Leaders in 4e are spending their actions for you

When a power allows a target to spend a healing surge, it does not require an action on the part of the target unless the power explicitly says otherwise.

> When a power heals you, you don’t have to take an action to spend a healing surge. Even if you’re unconscious, the power uses your healing surge and restores hit points. And some healing powers restore hit points without requiring you to spend a healing surge. (PHB1 p. 293)

Healing surges are a resource, just like hit points or any other resource your character might have. By themselves, there is nothing that you can do with them. There is no rule about spending actions to use them. Instead, certain powers allow you to spend them: Second Wind, healing potions, Inspiring Word, etc.

<sub>Thanks to [Mike Riverso](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/411/mike-riverso)</sub>